# ckeditor 5 Disabling content filtering

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I've notice when extracting the data from the editor it filters some classes and styles.
I want to use the exact same styling as the editor uses.

So, i have 2 problems i need to solve.

1. How can i prevent the filtering of classes and styles from happening.
2. How can i extract the CSS to a separate file?

I know when using previous ckeditor versions you could have used the following to prevent it filtering:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this ? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the General HTML support plugin in CKEditor 5. More info in the [docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/general-html-support.html)

This is what I'm using to enable some features as per my needs. You can customize to your implementation.

```
ClassicEditor.create(richEditorElem, {
  htmlSupport: {
    allow: [
      {
        name: /^(div|ul|li|ol|a|button|p|h[1-6])$/,
        classes: true,
        styles: true
      }
    ]
  }
}).then( editor => {

}).catch( error => {
    console.error( error );
});
```

Comment: Note that it's a "This is a feature in constant development.", it may or may not as expected.